# How to get Xorg to ignore certain input devices?

Tags: xorg, input-devices

What needs to be done so that when a specific input device is plugged in via USB it is not automatically used for input by X?  I still want the /dev/input/* device nodes automatically created, but don't want X to use them.

My xorg.conf currently only has sections for "Screen", "Monitor", "Display", "ServerLayout", and "Device" for my video card.  There are no sections for input.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Input devices are now managed in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` (in **10.04 Lucid**, the directory is `/usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d/`).

This directory contains configuration rules for all your input devices:

```
root@3000-G530:/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d# ls
10-evdev.conf      50-vmmouse.conf  51-synaptics-quirks.conf
50-synaptics.conf  50-wacom.conf    60-magictrackpad.conf
```

- You fist need to find your input device there, note that those files are "rules" matching a number of possible devices. 50-wacom.conf for example will handle every wacom device. Look throgh them to find which one is responsible for your device, or [create your own](http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/01/new-configuration-world-order.html).

To disable a device:

- Add the option `Option "Ignore" "true"` to the relevant configuration file.

  Open the file with root privileges (i.e. press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gksu gedit`) and add this option to the others.

Log out and back in for the changes to take effect.