# How do I disable my laptops builtin keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, default

I have a problem with my laptops default keyboard. It is broken... to sum up.

It gets stuck on the 'h' key and you see

ghsdhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh... ----> (arrow signifies that it goes on forever until I stop it)

I use a USB keyboard to type. I want to disable the default keyboard because I don't want to deal with this anymore. Is there a way to do that with ubuntu?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to: 
[How to get Xorg to ignore certain input devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17603/how-to-get-xorg-to-ignore-certain-input-devices)

> Input devices are now managed in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ (in 10.04 Lucid, the directory is /usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d/).
>   This directory contains configuration rules for all your input devices:
>
> root@3000-G530:/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d# ls
>   10-evdev.conf      50-vmmouse.conf  51-synaptics-quirks.conf
>   50-synaptics.conf  50-wacom.conf    60-magictrackpad.conf
>
> You fist need to find your input device there, note that those files are "rules" matching a number of possible devices. 50-wacom.conf for example will handle every wacom device. Look throgh them to find which one is responsible for your device, or create your own.
>   To disable a device:
>
> Add the option Option "Ignore" "true" to the relevant configuration file.
>
> Open the file with root privileges (i.e. press Alt+F2 and type gksu gedit) and add this option to the others.
>
> Log out and back in for the changes to take effect.